# How to change the preview result position of vim's taglist plugin (hitting 'p')

Tags: vim, taglist

While using a preview [p] or jump-to [enter] command in the taglist window, the appropriate line is by default  in the file-edit window. Because I mostly need to see more of what's right after the selected tag (functions), I'd love to change the line at which the tag is displayed from the center to let's say 1 third of the current page size (number of lines) or even to an explicit line (let's say 10th line from the top).

Is there a command/settings that would adjust the displayed position of a selected tag? (I couldn't find one in the manual).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, regarding the Ingo Karkat's comment, I managed to locate the appropriate line in the taglist plugin (begginning at line 3357, version 4.6):

```
" Jump to the tag
if a:tagpat != ''
    " Add the current cursor position to the jump list, so that user can
    " jump back using the ' and ` marks.
    mark '
    silent call search(a:tagpat, 'w')

    " Bring the line to the middle of the window
    normal! z.

    " If the line is inside a fold, open the fold
    if foldclosed('.') != -1
        .foldopen
    endif
endif
```

Here the part `normal! z.` needs to be changed appropriately to something that would change a position of the selected line appropriately. As I'm no vim-plugin guru, I changed it in the most dumb way possible as

```
" Bring the line to the middle of the window
normal! zt
normal! 10k
silent call search(a:tagpat, 'w')
```

which just walks 10times up and than searches the right position again. Hope this might help someone who 'struggles' with the same issue at the moment until a better solution is suggested or Yegappan Lakshmanan, the author, includes this (or rather something nicer) to his plugin (in case he decides to do that of course :) )

Answer (score 1):

You're presumably looking for the `zt` (redraw with current line at the top of the window), and `zz` (redraw at center) commands, or something in between (which can be achieved with `<C-Y>` / `<C-E>` after those commands).

How to incorporate that into the plugin is best discussed with the plugin's author. Since you've found no configuration setting for this, you likely have to directly modify the source code. Write your suggestion to the author; you may get a configuration / hook for this in the next plugin version, or tips how to do this, or maybe the author's opinion of why this is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for answer, though the zt/zz renders the cursor position in the actual taglist window. What I'm looking for is the result that is seen in the window attached to the tag I choose and hit p/enter to 'preview' or 'jump to' the line which the tag points to - this result I'd like to be displayed further up and not centered. Though thanks for the suggestion, I'll probably try to write a comment to the author

Comment: Right, that was what I was hinting at: The plugin jumps to the result window, then back to the taglist. In between, you'd have to insert the zt/zz, but that's only accessible inside the plugin so far.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to tweak the `scrolloff` setting. I don't know the tagbar plugin but I imagine setting `:set so=5` should provide you some context when jumping around.

Comment: Hey, that is fun feature I didn't know about! :D On it's own, it won't fix the problem, but it's working fine using the `normal! zt` patch to the taglist.vim plugin. Thank you for the hint